# Is it possible to silently update the ios app?

Tags: ios, app-store

is the any way to update ios app sliently (without user to go to appstore and hit update button)?

Our scenario is that we want to push update to users' device and update automatically at night when they are sleeping.

As far as I know there is no way to do that with normal Apple Dev Program license, but I have no experience with Enterprise License. What is typical configuration to make it possible?

UPDATE:
According to [this link](http://www.citeworld.com/article/2114859/mobile-byod/iOS7-mobile-management-mdm-mam.html), it's possible.

> Silent updates and installs -- All iOS 7 devices can now download and
>   install app updates without user interaction or notification. That
>   ability extends to business and enterprise devices. A companion
>   feature for devices, set up using Configurator's Supervise mode, also
>   supports silent or background installation of apps and updates pushed
>   out over the air by administrators, a useful feature in many settings
>   like schools, hospitals, retail, hospitality, and sales.

Comment: Maybe not immediately helpful, but the user can enable automatic updates.

Comment: Dude its not possible.

Comment: No this is not possible, not even with the enterprise license. The enterprise license does allows you to distribute your app outside of the AppStore so the install procedure is stil the same except that not a growers is used to update the app. Also with the enterprise license you can only distribute app to company employees.

Comment: @rckoenes i update my question, the article's statement seem to contradict to what you say. Or i misunderstood your comment?

Comment: @jAckOdE Yes, there is a silent update, as in iOS will update all apps if the user is connect to WiFi in background with the user going into the AppStore app and clicking Update. But this is not something you can trigger it is a setting in iOS for the AppStore. You can use a profile in an enterprise environment to push updates. But this does not apply to normal users.

Answer (score 2):

Silently full update your .app file, it seems, is not possible.

But you can update a some part of .app. It's a xml, png, jpg, configure files etc. by [Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) by HTTP requests.

But if you want update your app code, i have is not good idea: your code must be in Lua scripts and you can update any Lua script file by HTTP Requests in Background Executions.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to update your app on a user's phone by yourself. But here is some ideas:

- If the users has automatic updates turned on, your app will update by itself when iOS wants it.
- If you use a backend service like Parse.com, you can externalize some code and update it server side without the need to update the app.

Comment: it may require a major change in our current code base, so it's not an option for us atm.